# Selected Radio buttons value is null when run on iPad with iOS 7.1.2

Tags: javascript, ios, meteor, safari

I have written an app with Meteor. On one of the pages is a form with several fields for the user to fill in. When the page is filled in and submitted to the server I get null as my value for registrationType. (Only getting nulls on older iOS versions).

My HTML - displays correctly.

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <label><input type="radio" name="registrationType" value="Rider" {{registrationTypeChecked "Rider"}}>Rider</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="registrationType" value="Support Driver" {{registrationTypeChecked "Support Driver"}}>Support Driver</label>
</div>
```

My code to collect the data and send to Meteor method on server. Note I added the if block to test another way to try and get the value of the checked radio button. This also returns null.

```
Template.regoStep1.events({
  'submit .new-registration'(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const target = event.target;

    var registrationType = target.registrationType.value;

    if (registrationType === null) {
        var types = document.getElementsByName('registrationType');

        for(var i = 0; i < types.length; i++){
            if(types[i].checked){
                registrationType = types[i].value;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    ...

    Meteor.call('registrations.step1', registrationType, ...);
  }
});
```

My question: Is there a way to get the value of the checked radio button on older versions of safari?